# $c_{00}$ is not contained in maximal ideal

Tags: functional-analysis, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, banach-algebras

As the title says the problem is to show that $c_{00}$ is not contained in any maximal ideal ($c_{00}$ is considered lying in $c_0$). I am not used nonunital algebras (rings) so I don't know how to approach to questions like this.

Edit: $c_0 = \{ x_n \in \mathbb{C}, n \in \mathbb{N} : \lim x_n = 0 \}$ and $c_{00}$ is subspace (subalgebra) in $c_0$ with $x_n$ nonzero for only finitely  many indexes. I am sorry, I thought the notation was standard.

Comment: What is $c_00$, or $c_{00}$?

Comment: Sequences which are nonzero for only finite many indexes.

Comment: That is not standard notation here in the US at least. Edit your question for clarity.

Comment: ... and what is $c_0$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I've seen $c_{00}$ used in this way a lot (in the US)

Comment: @Régis sequences which converge to $0$

Comment: See it a lot does not make it standard. @mathworker21

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: I would say that it is definitely the standard notation in the US (and Canada, and everywhere else Banach algebras are used). I'm not aware of any other notation commonly used. And the notation is the one used in [the Wikipedia article on sequence spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space).

Comment: @MartinArgerami $c_0$ is certainly absolutely standard. Standard or not, I'd rather write $c_c$ for $c_{00}$. Because then $c_0=C_0(\Bbb N)$ and $c_c=C_c(\Bbb N)$.

Comment: By maximal ideal do you mean closed maximal ideal?

Comment: Isn't every maximal ideal closed?

Comment: Ok. Now i get it. Doesn't the fact that every maximal ideal is closed solve your question? You just have to use that $c_{00}$ is dense.

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez very nice

Comment: How do you prove that every maximal ideal is closed?

Comment: Yeah,why can’t a maximal ideal be dense?

Comment: Well if it closed and dense then it is the whole space hence not a *proper* ideal. But I don-t see why it should be closed (I am not even sure what topology we are talking about).

Comment: @Régis My point is that (I think) the closure of an ideal is an ideal and if the closure of a maximal ideal had to be proper, then it would be equal to the maximal ideal, of course.  But here we have an example of a dense ideal, so the closure of a proper ideal need not be proper. So why would it be the case for maximal ideals? That's what I'd like to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As remarked in the comments, $c_{00}$ is dense in $c_0$, so it suffices to show that every maximal ideal is closed. This is not true in general commutative Banach algebras.

But by Prop 3.1 and the discussion before that in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3815), we have that every dense maximal ideal $M$ in $c_{0}$ satisfies $c_{0}^2 \subset M$. But $c_{0}^2=c_{0}$, as one can take pointwise square roots of any sequence in $c_{0}$ and the resulting sequence still lies in $c_{0}$., thus having $c_{0}^2 \subset M$ is impossible for a proper ideal.

Comment: I don't see how $c_{00}^2=c_{00}$  and $c_{00}^2 \subset M$ contradicts that $c_{00} \subset M$.

Comment: @Régis you're right, I messed up the notation and wrote $c_{00}$ where it should be $c_0$